# Disbale jax-ws logging or static statements in generated services

Tags: java, log4j, jax-ws

When I generate service classes with jax-ws it generates a static statement like this:

```
static {
   URL url = null;
   try {
      URL baseUrl;
      baseUrl = com.some.package.with.class.getResource(".");
      url = new URL(baseUrl, "/META-INF/wsdl/thewsdl.wsdl");
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: '/META-INF/wsd/thewsdl.wsdl', retrying as a local file");
         logger.warning(e.getMessage());
    }
    SERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

Our WSDL's are packaged inside the jar meta-inf at the time we build, and we use our own factories to properly construct the various servies using the constructor that takes URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName. So this static statement ends up throwing misleading warnings that are not really a problem for us. I also cannot easily configure the logger to ignore them (that I can tell) because each service is its own namespace (com.some.package) We have a lot of different packages and I would rather be able to do something universal than having to list each service class in the log config.

Is there any way to have jax-ws not generate this static block at all? or does anyone know of a easy way to disable logging for all service classes in one swoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a good answer for this. A kludge fix is to set the wsdl location to http like http://localhost:8080//META-INF/wsdl/thewsdl.wsdl

This stops the static block from throwing the warning but then requires you to manipulate the location when you want to construct the service. Just handing in one evil for another.